# runOnUiThread vs Looper.getMainLooper().post in Android

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me if there's any difference between using `runOnUiThread()` versus `Looper.getMainLooper().post()` to execute a task on the UI thread in Android??

The only thing I can determine is that since runOnUiThread is a non-static Activity method, `Looper.getMainLooper().post()` is more convenient when you need to code something in a class that can't see the Activity (such as an interface).

I'm not looking for a discussion on WHETHER something should be executed on the UI thread, I get that some things can't and a great many things shouldn't, however, some things (like starting up an AsyncTask) MUST be executed from the UI thread.

Comment: There is no difference except that `runOnUiThread` will check if it is already the UI thread and execute your task directly instead of posting it as a `Message`

Comment: Thanks.  Would you please convert that to an answer, so I can accept it??

Comment: Also, I've already written some code to check if something is being executed on the UI thread, so that would be very simple to include manually.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

The following behaves the same when called from background threads:

- using `Looper.getMainLooper()`

  ```
  Runnable task = getTask();
  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(task);
  ```
- using `Activity#runOnUiThread()`

  ```
  Runnable task = getTask();
  runOnUiThread(task);
  ```

The only difference is when you do that from the UI thread since

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);
    } else {
        action.run();
    }
}
```

will check if the current Thread is already the UI thread and then execute it directly. Posting it as a message will delay the execution until you return from the current UI-thread method.

There is also a third way to execute a `Runnable` on the UI thread which would be [`View#post(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) - this one will always post the message even when called from the UI thread. That is useful since that will ensure that the `View` has been properly constructed and has a layout before the code is executed.