# AcitivtyName.this.finish() is not working in callbacks

Tags: android, android-activity, android-volley

I have written a Class to perform network operation using Volley and have callback passed in the method.
Code is as below

```
public class MyNetUtil {

    public interface MyNetCallbacks {
        public void onResponse(String response);

        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error);

        public void onErrorResponseData(ErrorResponseData error);

        public void onResponseCode(int code);

    }

    private void request(int method, String url, final Map<String, String> headMap, final byte[] bodyContent, final MyNetCallbacks myNetCallbacks) {
        Log.d(TAG, " Getting url : " + url);

        final StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(method, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response);
                if (myNetCallbacks != null) {
                    myNetCallbacks.onResponse(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                int statusCode = -1;
                if (error != null && error.networkResponse != null) {
                    statusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                }


                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                ErrorResponseData errorResponseData = null;
                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                    String errorResponse = new String(response.data);
                    if (statusCode == -1) {
                        statusCode = response.statusCode;
                    }
                    errorResponseData = ErrorResponseData.getResponseData(errorResponse);
                }
                if (myNetCallbacks != null) {
                    myNetCallbacks.onErrorResponse(error);
                    if (statusCode != -1) {
                        myNetCallbacks.onResponseCode(statusCode);
                    }
                    myNetCallbacks.onErrorResponseData(errorResponseData);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, " inside onErrorResponse " + statusCode);

            }
        }) {
//            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
//                return stringMap;
//            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                Log.d(TAG, "Body : " + new String(bodyContent));
                return bodyContent;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON;
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "  inside parseNetworkResponse, responseCode : " + response.statusCode);
                if (myNetCallbacks != null) {
                    myNetCallbacks.onResponseCode(response.statusCode);
                }
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON);
                headers.put("Accept", "application/api.ryder.v2");
                headers.put("Authentication-Token", getAuthToken());

                if (headMap != null) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headMap.entrySet()) {
                        headers.put(entry.getKey() + "", entry.getValue() + "");
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, " Header ");
                Util.displayMap(TAG, headers);
                return headers;
            }
        };
        BaseApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, "");
    }



}
```

In my Activity I use it as

```
 private MyNetUtil mMyNetUtil = new MyNetUtil();

            mMyNetUtil.request(Request.Method.DELETE, url, headMap, bodyContent, new MyNetUtil.MyNetCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showProgress(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    showProgress(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponseData(ErrorResponseData error) {
                    showProgress(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponseCode(int code) {
                    showProgress(false);
                    setInfoMessage(R.string.alert__lbl__your_account_was_deleted_successfully);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponseCode " + code);
                    if (code == MyNetUtil.CODE_204) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FINISH --------- " + code);
                        DataUser.deleteUserFromPref();
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.alert__lbl__your_account_was_deleted_successfully, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ActivityProfile.this.finish();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        setErrorMessage(R.string.server_error);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Control is going till `ActivityProfile.this.finish();`

but the activity is not getting `finished`
I tried onBackPressed also that also not working.

But when I call `ActivityProfile.this.finish()` out side callback it getting finished

what could be the issue, please help me

Comment: Would you please provide the logcat?

Answer (score 4):

You should only call `finish` from the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

`parseNetworkResponse` runs on non UI thread.

That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974661/runonuithread-vs-looper-getmainlooper-post-in-android).

Or check [this](https://github.com/pepperonas/AppRegistry/blob/master/showcase/src/main/java/com/pepperonas/appregistry/showcase/MainActivity.java#L78).