# Click on a button after 2 seconds

Tags: java, android

When I click on a button, another button should be clicked programmatically after 2 seconds.

```java
Helper.setTimeout(() -> {
    _view.findViewById(R.id.turbineStandBy).performClick();
}, 2000);
```

When I run this code, I get this exception:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
> views.

```java
public static void setTimeout(Runnable runnable, int delay){
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            runnable.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I think that I have to override the method `run()` but how can I do that in my setTimeout() method?

Comment: What is this Helper.setTimeout in the first place?

Comment: @hata `Helper` is the class of my method `setTimeout()`. The code of `setTimeout()` you see in my post.

Comment: It's your original method. So you can redefine it rather than overriding `run()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
> views.

The exception tells you that you must run the `Runnable` in the main thread. To do so, you can use `Looper.getMainLooper` or `Activity#runOnUIThread` (cf. [runOnUiThread vs Looper.getMainLooper().post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974916/3501958)).

Below codes are structural examples (you might still need to make somewhat modification).

Using `Looper.getMainLooper`:

```
public void setTimeout(Runnable runnable, int delay) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(runnable, delay);
}
```

Using `Activity#runOnUIThread`:

```
public void setTimeout(Activity activity, Runnable runnable, int delay) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            activity.runOnUIThread(runnable);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

(Note: I don't know whether you should put `static` modifier to the method or not.)

Apparently, in your case you want to make delay, using `Looper.getMainLooper` combined with `Handler#postDelayed` looks smarter.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just use post delayed method
2. ```
   button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
           //click your button here

             }
         },2000);
     });
   ```